# Mysql Error Only When Run Via a Bash Script

Tags: mysql, bash

So I am very new to databases, but I have done some research and I thought that I had figured everything out that I needed but I am running into an error when I try to run my script.

This is my script

```
  mysql -h portal-rds -u $user --password=$mysqlpw <<QUERY_INPUT
  CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $DATABASE
  use $DATABASE
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS backUpFiles (fileName VARCHAR(20), archiveId VARCHAR(500), checkSum VARCHAR(100), glacierVault VARCHAR(100), timeStamp date);
  INSERT INTO backUpFiles
  VALUES ('$archive_file_name', '$archiveID', '$CURRENTVAULT', '$checkSum', CURDATE());
  QUERY_INPUT
```

The Error I am recieving is

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'use glacier

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS backUpFiles (fileName VARCHAR(20), archiveId VARCHAR(500), checkSum VARCHAR(100), glacierVault VARCHAR(100), timeStamp date);
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

I then decided to manually log into mysql and run this commands and they worked fine besides this one warning which shouldn't break anything (I believe)

```
mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                            |
+-------+------+------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1050 | Table 'backupfiles' already exists |
+-------+------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.28 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `;` as the statement separator after the `CREATE DATABASE` statement.

The statement should look like this:

```
mysql -h portal-rds -u $user --password=$mysqlpw <<QUERY_INPUT
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $DATABASE; <---- were missing
use $DATABASE
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS backUpFiles (fileName VARCHAR(20), archiveId VARCHAR(500), checkSum VARCHAR(100), glacierVault VARCHAR(100), timeStamp date);
INSERT INTO backUpFiles
VALUES ('$archive_file_name', '$archiveID', '$CURRENTVAULT', '$checkSum', CURDATE());
QUERY_INPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed ;(semicolon) for the first two sql statements.

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $DATABASE;
use $DATABASE;